# Eliminating vertical spacing between subfigure rows

Tags: subcaption

I'm trying to determine how to eliminate vertical spacing between the rows of a `subfigure` generated using the `subcaption` package.

Currently I have

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{(#2)}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=bold}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

% Sub-Figure Example
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \captionsetup{width=.9\linewidth}
  \centering
  % Figure row 1
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\linewidth]{coffee.jpg}
      \put (5,40) {\color{white} A}
    \end{overpic}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\linewidth]{coffee.jpg}
      \put (5,40) {\color{white} B}
    \end{overpic}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\linewidth]{coffee.jpg}
      \put (5,40) {\color{white} C}
    \end{overpic}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:c}
  \end{subfigure}
  % Figure row 2
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
    \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\linewidth]{coffee.jpg}
      \put (1.5,48) {\color{white} D}
    \end{overpic}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:d}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{This is a figure. \subref{fig:a} This is a cup of coffee. \subref{fig:b} This is another cup of coffee. \subref{fig:c} This is more coffee.  \subref{fig:d} This is a big cup of coffee.}
  \label{fig:coffee3}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I'm trying to determine how to eliminate the white space between the row containing `A`, `B` and `C` and the row containing `D`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `\phantomcaption` skips a line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bold}{\textbf{(#2)}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=bold}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

% Sub-Figure Example
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=.9\textwidth}

% Figure row 1
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (5,40) {\color{white} A}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (5,40) {\color{white} B}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (5,40) {\color{white} C}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{overpic}[percent,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \put (1.5,48) {\color{white} D}
  \end{overpic}
  \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\caption{This is a figure. \subref{fig:a} This is a cup of coffee. 
  \subref{fig:b} This is another cup of coffee. \subref{fig:c} This is more coffee.  
  \subref{fig:d} This is a big cup of coffee.}
\label{fig:coffee3}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid `utf8x`, it's unsupported and unnecessary nowadays. The default is `utf8`, so you don't even need to load `inputenc`.

Also `[h!]` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Ah .. interesting ... Thanks!  As an aside, would there be a way to make an image span rows using something like this?

Comment: It's also interesting to see that `put` changes the placement of the label with `example-image` vs. `coffee.jpg`

Comment: @agf1997 Your image is less tall than the one I used